# SQL Server 2008 openrowset

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with openrowset in SQL Server 2008.

I'm running the following encoding:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Procesos\PRUEBA.xlsx', [Hoja1$])
```

And I get the following error:

> The OLE DB Provider 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' Can not be used for
>   distributed queries Because it is configured to run on the Simple
>   controlled threading mode.
>
> (El proveedor OLE DB 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'  no puede usarse para
>   consultas distribuidas  porque está configurado para ejecutarse en el 
>   modo de subprocesamiento controlado simple.)

Answer (score 0):

From [this thread on DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54675/openrowset-how-to-configure-ole-db-provider-to-be-used-for-for-distributed-que),you should enable this option first..

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Comment: HI, friend .
I already run the command but the same I still get the same error